# korn shell Unable to substitute ' ' (2 quotes) with ' (single quote) in a string variable

Tags: ksh, string, replace

I am trying to substitute `''2019-01-14''` to `'2019-01-14'` in a varible `$STG`.
I tried various techniques

```
echo ${STG//''/'}
echo $STG | sed -e s/'\'\''/'\''/g
```

many more none of the equations are working.

Comment: Do you just want the variable to be set as `'2019-01-14'`?

Comment: yes I want the variable to be set as '2019-01-14'. Below all just echo or print the value but the variable still remains the same with double quotes at the end.

Comment: You're not being clear on what you want. If you want to set the variable as `'2019-01-14'` then just `export STG=\'2019-01-14\'`. If you do that then it doesn't remain the same with double quotes at the end. Otherwise, assign that value to another variable and call that one so that you don't need `tr` or `sed` or any other rigmarole to get the output that you want. You're complicating things where it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3):

escaping is working:

```
$ echo ${STG//\'\'/\'}
'2019-01-14'
```

or you can use tr:

```
$ echo "$STG" | tr -s "'"
'2019-01-14'
```

sed is overkill here, but working if you use quotes correctly:

```
$ echo "$STG" | sed -e "s/''/'/g"                        
'2019-01-14'
```